# How to loop in all data having key names including some text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-data

Assume I have an element like:

`<a id="button" data-param1="123" data-param2="456" ... data-paramN="1324" data-anotherName="908678" >Click This</a>`

I want to loop in all data having key names including "param" text. For example:

```
$('a#button').data('param%').each(function(){
   ...
});
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `.data()` function which automatically decodes `data-*` attributes and returns them in an object: http://api.jquery.com/data/#data

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ET4ER/2/

```
$.each( $('a#button').data(), function( key, value ){
    if( key.substr( 0, 5 ) !== 'param') return;
    $('<div>').text( key+'='+ value ).appendTo('body');
});
```

Result:

```
paramn=1324
param2=456
param1=123
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :data() selector from jquery ui: http://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/

Of course you would have to loop through result set and pick the specific ones you want with something like :contains()